Docker desktop not running on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Ubuntu gives the following error when starting docker desktop
~ ExecutablePath

Jopt/docker-desktop/Docker Desktop
v Package
docker-desktop 4.34.3-170107 [origin: unknown]
\ ProblemType
Crash
© Title
Docker Desktop crashed with SIGTRAP in 772()
\ ApportVersion
2.28.1-Oubuntu3.1
© Architecture
amd64
\ CasperMDSCheckResult
pass

CoreDump
\ CrashCounter
1
\ Date
FriNov 15 11:11:44 2024
Dependencies
Disassembly
~ DistroRelease
Ubuntu 24.04
~ InstallationDate
Installed on 2024-10-14 (32 days ago)
~ InstallationMedia
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS "Noble Numbat" - Release amd64 (202408271)
~ JournalErrors
Nov 15 11:11:43 nout gnome-shell[3258]: Could not create transient scope For PID 15520: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessidUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
\ PackageArchitecture
amd64
v Proccmdline
Jopt/docker-desktop/Docker\ Desktop\ ~analytics-enabled=true-name=new-license
ProcCpuinfoMinimal
v Proccwd
‘[home/name

© ProcEnviron

ProcMaps
ProcStatus
\ ProcVersionSignature
Ubuntu 6.8.0-48.48-generic 6.8.12
Registers
\ Signal
5
\ SignalName
SIGTRAP
\ SourcePackage
docker-desktop
Stacktrace
StacktraceTop
\ Tags
noble third-party-packages wayland-session
ThreadStacktrace
¥ uname
Linux 6.8.0-48-generic x86_64
\ UnreportableReason

\ UpgradeStatus
No upgrade log present (probably Fresh install)
\ UserGroups
adm cdrom dip docker lpadmin plugdev sudo users
separator
Asked GPT he replied - The problem with the SIGTRAP signal can be complex as it can be caused by many factors including conflicts with system resources or software. By following the above recommendations, you will be able to gather more information about the problem and possibly find a solution. If the problem persists, it is recommended that you contact the Docker or Ubuntu community for support.
